# Depending on the connection website may or may not load

Tags: wordpress, performance, caching

So I have a site am working on however I have had people call in with the issue that it doesn't load and its a blank screen and sometimes when it finally loads it's extremely slow. On my end I have checked using phone data, broadbands WiFi and on desktop. It loads fine for me. I had a friend check and it loads on her mobile data but not WiFi. On someone else's it doesn't load at all. One thin thing I noticed is the video which might be the cause but I have checked the page load event and even if its the video loading it doest explain the vast difference on it loading for some people and not for others. Its a WordPress site with plugins and cache. Since I can't replicate the loading issues my end am wondering if there is any way I can actually identify the issue so I can get it working for all.
The site is www.nourishbay.co.uk

Thanks

Comment: something's probably wrong with Thumbs Rating plugin, it's outputting bad urls:
https://nourishbay.co.ukthumbs_rating_url/js/general.js?ver=4.0.1

Comment: Thats just a missing slash making the file not load. It's not that. I think the WiFi is slow its unable to dowlmod the image nd it just gets stuck. It only happens on some WiFi connections, not all. That's the strange bit